# Set values to column only in DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable which has several rows already. Now I want to add a column and populate values for that column alone in all the rows. One way is to iterate over all the rows and put values for that column alone. Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: That sounds like an entirely reasonable way to do it to me. I doubt that the code looks particularly nasty... any reason you're looking for an alternative?

Comment: Whatever method you choose will require you to iterate over the rows, so no.  *How* you write the code might be improved, but it will need to do the iteration regardless.